# Undefined error when accessing JSON Objects

Tags: json, parsing

I jave my JSON file as below and want to access an element. I am getting undefined error while parsing the JSON(result.JSON)

```
{
"id": "#123456",
"gender": {
    "male" : "MALE",
    "female" : "FEMALE"
    },
 "role": {
    "admin" : "Admin login",
    "guest" : "Guest user login"
  }
 }
```

So, I wanted to access the value of admin from above JSON. I have tried the following but getting undefined error

```
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)).role.admin)
```

Comment: I tried this one too, but then I got "Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1". So added stringify which resolved that

Comment: You can only properly stringify a parsed object.  This is why it doesn't make any sense, or you posted  a different json.

Comment: The JSON is the same one, but modified the names here. (like user_role to role...when I changed the names in JSON, it worked perfectly)

Answer (score -2):

Your code worked fine for me
[image]

I think there is nothing wrong, your code worked fine.

Also `console.log(result.role.admin)` simply works

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others. also please do not take a screenshot of your solution. instead, edit your answer and put the code itself here. your answer is already marked as low-quality and will be removed if you don't edit it.